# Why is this Cross Join so Slow in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, cross-join

I wrote this piece of Linq to handle doing a CROSS Join just like a database would between multiple lists.

But for some reason it's extremely slow when any of the lists go more than 3000. I'd wait for 30s ? These lists could go to very large numbers.

This query is looped for each relationship with the other list's data coming from **ColumnDataIndex**.

Any Advice ?

UPDATE ** - The data is inserted into normal lists that are built before hand from the configured sources. This is all in memory at the moment.

```
RunningResult[parameter.Uid] = (from source_row in RunningResult[parameter.Uid]
                            from target_row in ColumnDataIndex[dest_key]
                            where GetColumnFromUID(source_row, rel.SourceColumn) == GetColumnFromUID(target_row, rel.TargetColumn)
                            select new Row()
                            {
                                Columns = MergeColumns(source_row.Columns, target_row.Columns)

                            }).ToList();
```

The 2 extra functions:

**MergeColumns**: Takes the Columns from the 2 items and merges them into a single array.

```
public static Columnn[] MergeColumns(Column[] source_columns, Column[] target_columns)
{
      Provider.Data.BucketColumn[] new_column = new Provider.Data.BucketColumn[source_columns.Length + target_columns.Length];
      source_columns.CopyTo(new_column, 0);
      target_columns.CopyTo(new_column, source_columns.Length);
      return new_column;
  }
```

**GetColumnFromUID**: Returns the Value of the Column in the Item matching the column uid given.

```
private static String GetColumnFromUID(Row row, String column_uid)
  {
       if (row != null)
       {
           var dest_col = row.Columns.FirstOrDefault(col => col.ColumnUid == column_uid);
           return dest_col == null ? "" + row.RowId : dest_col.Value.ToString().ToLower();
       }
       else return String.Empty;

  }
```

Update:

**Ended up moving the data and the query to a database. This reduced to the speed to a number of ms. Could have written a optimized looped function but this was the fastest way out for me.**

Comment: Where are you defining your datasources, inside or outside of the loop. If outside, are they queryable sources or lists.

Comment: I'm building them outside the loop see above

Comment: My advice: **run a profiler.** Anything else is guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need to be performing a cross join.  *Cross joins are inherently expensive operations.*  You shouldn't be doing that unless you really need it.  In your case what you really need is just an inner join.  You're performing a cross join which is resulting in lots of values that you don't need at all, and then you're filtering out a huge percentage of those values to leave you with the few that you need.  If you just did an inner join from the start you would only compute the values that you need.  That will save you from needing to create a whole lot of rows you don't need just to have them be thrown away.

LINQ has its own inner join operation, `Join`, so you don't even need to write your own:

```
RunningResult[parameter.Uid] = (from source_row in RunningResult[parameter.Uid]
                                join target_row in ColumnDataIndex[dest_key]
                                on GetColumnFromUID(source_row, rel.SourceColumn) equals
                                    GetColumnFromUID(target_row, rel.TargetColumn)
                                select new Row()
                                {
                                    Columns = MergeColumns(source_row.Columns, target_row.Columns)

                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Ended up moving this query to a database but this answer did speed up the query while I was testing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing a cross join, but an inner join with an ON clause, only in your case, the ON clause in the where predicate.

An inner join is typically done with two hash sets/tables, so you can quickly find the row in set X based on the value in row Y.

So 'weston's answer is OK, yet you need to use dictionaries/hashtables to make it really fast. Be aware that it might be there are more rows per key. You can use a multi-value hashtable/dictionary like this one for that:
https://github.com/SolutionsDesign/Algorithmia/blob/master/SD.Tools.Algorithmia/GeneralDataStructures/MultiValueDictionary.cs

Comment: He is actually doing a cross join.  He only *needs* to do an inner join, given his example, and doing an inner join would greatly improve performance.  The fact that he's doing a cross join in order to get the same results as an inner join is the reason for the performance problems.  Note that LINQ has a `join` operator that he can use to perform an inner join; he doesn't need to create his own hash tables to do it (although he certainly could).

Comment: I just looked at the example, nothing more. The example does this: SELECT ... FROM X, Y WHERE X.field = Y.field; Same thing. The from .. from clauses indeed would imply a cross join, yet the where clause makes it semantically not a cross join. Or better: his query using the from... from construct isn't optimal for what he wants to do. I do know that Linq has a join operator, trust me ;)

Comment: The fact that he uses a SelectMany followed by a Where means that he is indeed doing a cross join.  That's the definition of a SelectMany *which is what the `From X from Y ...` maps to.  He's doing a cross join and then filtering the results into what the results of an inner join would have been.  That's a *lot* more time consuming than doing a Join right from the start as you avoid a LOT of unneeded overhead.